# How do I remove this crank?

Tags: crankset

I'm a novice in the process of restoring a 1987 Raleigh Equipe.

I'm managed to strip the rest of the bike but haven't attempted to remove the crank yet, can someone advise me on what tools I would need.

Thank you.

[image: Crank]

[image: Crank Drive Side]

Comment: That is a nice bike - do it well and you'll be sitting pretty.  It looks to have a cartridge bottom bracket already, which is a sealed unit and unserviceable.  If its knackered you'll need to buy a replacement, but if the BB is working fine, you might not need to take the cranks off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need a crank puller. On the left crank remove the bolt, then the crank puller screws in to the threaded part of the crank (black part of crank puller in picture below). You tighten the center part of the crank puller and it slowly pulls the crank from the spindle.

The same goes for the right crank, from the picture you've posted you first have to remove the cap using a wide screwdriver or thin coin.

[image: crank puller]

You can find crank pullers on ebay quite cheaply or go to your local bike shop.